¿Como puedo downgrade degradar bajar la version de Python 3.8?
Hola buenas estoy usando Termux para correr un repositorio de github y lamentablemente con la ultima version de python la 3.11.9 (esa es la que se me instala) tengo errores de compatibilidad
Tengo este problema Python py project unable to build wheel
linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/SgiRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/TgaRleEncode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/libImaging/codec_fd.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/map.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/outline.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/src/path.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -L/system/lib64 -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -ljpeg -lz -lpython3.11 -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311.so
aarch64-linux-android-clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath'
aarch64-linux-android-clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath'
error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang' failed with exit code 1**

**note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
Failed to build pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tengo entendido que es por la version de Python por lo que estuve investigando en foros, Creen que me puedan ayudar explicandome el como puedo obtener la version de python 3.8 en Termux. Muchas gracias, No se mucho de Linux o de Termux, si me pueden apoyar se los agradeceria mucho de corazon. Y si se pueden tomar el tiempo igual de enseñarme paso a paso como instalar
pkg install rust libjpeg-turbo libcrypt ndk-sysroot clang zlib binutils tur-repo
LDFLAGS="-L${PREFIX}/lib/" CFLAGS="-I${PREFIX}/include/" pip install --upgrade wheel pillow

sin afectar el python 3.8 Muchas gracias de corazon
Encontre que mas gente tiene el mismo problema y dieron 3 soluciones pero no entiendo en como hacer eso, por eso vi que la mas facil era cambiando la version de python, pero igual no se hacer eso
https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/20039

Eso sería trivial en una distro Linux x64, lo más simple usar PyEnv, pero termux/Android... No estoy muy al día, pero que yo sepa lo más simple es usar TUR, supongo que podrías también compilar por ti mismo Python. No obstante, ¿has probado la solución que enlazas? Porque es modificar un simple archivo, lo cual puedes hacer ejecutando los cuatro comandos que te muestran simplemente o abriendo el archivo en un editor de texto.

Hola mucho gusto, me podrias explicar porfa como ejecutar los 4 comandos, o como abrir ese editor de texto en Termux gracias

Simplemente copialos y ejecútalos en la terminal (termux) pulsando Enter. En cuanto a los cuatro comandos, a grandes rasgos el primero  busca el archivo (find) y lo almacena en la variable de BASH (_file), el segundo elimina (rm)  la versión compilada a bytecode del script para forzar su recompilación, el tercero crea una copia de seguridad del archivo (cp) por si algo va mal lo puedas restaurar y el cuarto realiza la modificación el archivo (sed).

No se si funciona o no, no lo he probado, pero dado que a otros les ha funcionado no pierdes nada por intentarlo y es una solución muy simple. Si no, puedes intentar instalando python 3.8 desde TUR.

Gracias por contestar de nuevo, perdoname no entiendo mucho todavia del lenguaje linux y menos lo que me contestaste, crees que me puedas grabar un video te lo agradeceria mucho si crees poder hacerlo, enserio que trato de entenderte y buscar otros videos pero no encuentro. gracias de nuevo. te refieres al $PREFIX/lib/python3.11/_sysconfigdata*.py   y al _file="$(find $PREFIX/lib/python3.11 -name "_sysconfigdata*.py")"
rm -rf $PREFIX/lib/python3.11/pycache
cp $_file "$_file".backup
sed -i 's|-fno-openmp-implicit-rpath||g' "$_file"   DE SOLUCION? gracias FJSevilla
